# Bootstrap: Is popover broken in version 2.2.2?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have updated to the latest 2.2.2 version of bootstrap and it seems manual triggering of popovers are broken:

here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/houmie/XRSFr/26/) to proof it.

Once you click on the button, check your console it says:

```
TypeError: e is undefined
```

In bootstrap line 1010:

```
toggle: function (e) {
  var self = $(e.currentTarget)[this.type](this._options).data(this.type)
  self[self.tip().hasClass('in') ? 'hide' : 'show']()
}
```

It seems `e` is undefined.

Can anyone else confirm this? then I could submit a bug. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I submitted the bug.  It will be fixed in the next version 2.3.0

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/6628#issuecomment-12425043